# SSH new connection refuses

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, putty

I think the correct question I had was how to rebuild SSH after removing a important file. But I can't fix this online anymore.

I you have an answer you can link it for others to find.

---

<strike>Right now I'm connected to my VPN server with PuTTy.</strike> 
After this edit I close the connection I've had up, thanks for trying to help me. 
I also had FilleZill (sftp connection to same server), but after a removing a folder (/home/user1) I can not establish any new connections to the server.

Every time I open the connection in PuTTy or any other SSH client / sftp client i get the message: `Network Error: Software caused connection to abort`

---

My SSH key is located in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

And my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` looks good.

My commands still execute so I don't have any internet problems in the terminal I'm still in, but if I leave it I can't reconnect.

My VPN is on a Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy) and PC is Windows 10

I've not restarted the PC for a or so day, I could try restart but not before I close the connection.

---

Log from FileZilla (PuTTy did not output anything)

```
> 21:07:57  Status: Disconnected from server 21:07:57   Status: Resolving address of SERVER 
> 21:07:57  Status: Connecting to SERVER:PORT...
> 21:07:57  Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...             
> 21:07:57  Trace:  CRealControlSocket::OnClose(0)
> 21:07:57  Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
> 21:07:57  Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
> 21:07:57  Error:  Could not connect to server 
> 21:07:57  Status: Waiting to retry... 
> 21:08:02  Status: Resolving address of SERVER
> 21:08:02  Status: Connecting to SERVER:PORT...
> 21:08:02  Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...    
> 21:08:02  Trace:  CRealControlSocket::OnClose(0)
> 21:08:02  Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
> 21:08:02  Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
> 21:08:02  Error:  Could not connect to server
```

It's like my computer refuses to open a new connection, as it's fine with the connection I already have.

---

Looking at the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file i remembered that I'm logging in with a authentication key, witch is like the most important thing for my server and I freak out every time something happens to it. 
With that said, I won't have the server up with only password.

<strike>I got this revelation that I should check the authentication log and I found this:</strike>

```
Sep 27 08:11:30 Host sshd[XXXXX]: Did not receive identification string from <IP-address>
```

I'm already on it, I'm coming back with more info.

Turns out that wasn't me, I didn't recognized the IP because it was from China.
But now I know that my login tries are not reaching the server.

Witch would explain why I get the Network Error so fast, like before even trying to communicate with server.

---

I've discussed the issue with my provider and it's seems like even though I recreated the file the SSH service is broken as I could not restart/reload it from the inside.

At this point I should look up how to rebuild SSH for my server, but I think my provider need to take care of that as I can't connect and the server is located on the other side of the country.

Comment: Try adding more information to your question. First, are you still connected to the server and what kind of connection (you mentioned 2)? Second, did you successfully logged in as root? Third, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to say I'm connected, but I can't reconnect. i'm updating the questiion.

Comment: Are you sure you didnt remove the wrong home directory (and your ssh key with it)? Anyway you have to turn on verbose logging in putty somehow and add that info to your question.

Comment: I did remove the wrong home directory (the one I keep my important stuff like my website and some scripts :/), but I've recreated the key file. Although I'm not logging in with that account. I got a log from FileZilla, but it does not say much, PuTTy gave me nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Connection for user 'root' must be allowed in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
- For accounts without $HOME (home dir) isn't allowed interactive
  login

**so, for first part of problem:**

- From 'man sshd_config':

> PermitRootLogin
>
> ```
>      Specifies whether root can   log in using ssh(1).  The argument
>      must be ``yes'', ``without-password'', ``forced-commands-only'',
>      or ``no''.  The default is ``no''.  Note that if
>      ChallengeResponseAuthentication is ``yes'', the root user may be
>      allowed in with its password even if PermitRootLogin is set to
>      ``without-password''.
>
>      If this option is set to ``without-password'', password authenti-
>      cation is disabled for root.
>
>      If this option is set to ``forced-commands-only'', root login
>      with public key authentication will be allowed, but only if the
>      command option has been specified (which may be useful for taking
>      remote backups even if root login is normally not allowed).  All
>      other authentication methods are disabled for root.
>
>      If this option is set to ``no'', root is not allowed to log in.
> ```

**and for second:**

look to '/etc/passwd' for line with user as you login, and create right home directory with proper rights

btw: use your filezilla sftp connection or direct access

Comment: I've always been able to login as root user, in fact I don't even know how to do it any other way. It's just that for some reason it stopped working when I removed one users home directory. 
I'm sure my server was setup with all the correct login information when I got it. 
Anyhow I'll try the second part, but after that I'll have no access because I really need to shut off this computer and I can't keep a connection forever.
Also I told you in my question that I used FileZilla and PuTTy and the result of that..

Comment: You know what I tried both parts, the thing is that I use a authentication key, witch I've specified explicitly in the very same file.
But I found something else, I'm going to edit the question again.

Comment: i don't know default settings of debian's ssh, for upstream ssh is by default root login disabled.

Comment: I'll mark yours as an answer as it help everyone else who uses password I guess.